# How do I delete a wall in Timber and Stone?

Tags: timber-and-stone

I was building a wall and placed an order to build a timber door. I noticed later that there is a door and a wall overlapping each other.

I tried to dig/mine but to no avail. Any suggestions or a possible way to remove that piece of wall?

Comment: That's what I said in my question. _I tried to dig/mine but to no avail_